# PTIJ: Shatnez issues with FLAC audio files

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Being that there is a prohibition of Sha'atnez when wearing wool and linen (or flax) may one listen to FLACs (FLAC audio files) while wearing a wool sweater?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: one may wear two clothes one if linen and one of wool in certain circumstances why is this different